# What is a "NullReferenceError" in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I keep getting "NullReferenceError" in my output, could someone kindly explain what exactly this statement means.

Comment: Does it mean no data has been input?

Comment: I think you may need to provide some more explanation...if it's an exception, do you have a stack trace? - If not, what are the steps you follow to reproduce?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your code, you are trying to access a member of a reference type, but the variable actually is `null`. Without code and a stacktrace it's impossible to say what exactly happens. It might be because some parameter is expecting a value but isn't supplied one.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, a decent description of `NullReferenceException` -- why/when they occur, and how to prevent them -- at http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullreferenceexception